# Unit Test ASP.NET Web API controller with fake HTTPContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using the following approach to upload files through ASP.NET Web API controllers.

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    try
    {
        int id = 0;
        int? qId = null;
        if (int.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["id"], out id))
        {
            qId = id;
        }

        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

        int filePursuitId = bl.UploadFile(qId, file);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

    return response;
}
```

In my unit tests I've created an `HTTPContext` class manually before calling the `UploadFile` action:

```
var request = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost", "");
var context = new HttpContext(request, new HttpResponse(new StringWriter()));
HttpContext.Current = context;

response = controller.UploadFile();
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to add custom values to the `Form` collection, since it's read-only. Also I couldn't change the `Files` collection.

Is there any way to add custom values to the `Form` and `Files` properties of the `Request` to add needed data (id and file content) during the unit test?

Answer (score 1):

Use some mocking framework like [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) instead. Create a mock HttpRequestBase and mock HttpContextBase with whatever data you need and set them on the controller.

```
using Moq;
using NUnit.Framework;
using SharpTestsEx;

namespace StackOverflowExample.Moq
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public string UploadFile()
        {
            return Request.Form["id"];
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class WebApiTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Should_return_form_data()
        {
            //arrange
            var formData = new NameValueCollection {{"id", "test"}};
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            request.SetupGet(r => r.Form).Returns(formData);
            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            context.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

            var myController = new MyController();
            myController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), myController);

            //act
            var result = myController.UploadFile();

            //assert
            result.Should().Be.EqualTo(formData["id"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Since we use web.api controllers we need to use HttpControllerContext instead of ControllerContext. HttpControllerContext doesn't allow to pass in the constructor HttpContextBase.

Comment: just wondering why this was upvoted when Pylyp Lebediev said is true...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no control over those classes why not wrap/abstract the functionality behind one do control

```
IRequestService request;

[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadFile() {
    HttpResponseMessage response;

    try {
        int id = 0;
        int? qId = null;
        if (int.TryParse(request.GetFormValue("id"), out id)) {
            qId = id;
        }

        var file = request.GetFile(0);

        int filePursuitId = bl.UploadFile(qId, file);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //...
    }

    return response;
}
```

Where `request` is one of your custom defined types `IRequestService`

```
public interface IRequestService {
    string GetFormValue(string key);
    HttpPostedFileBase GetFile(int index);
    //...other functionality you may need to abstract
}
```

and can be implemented like this to be injected into your controller

```
public class RequestService : IRequestService {

    public string GetFormValue(string key) {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key];
    }

    public HttpPostedFileBase GetFile(int index) {
        return new HttpPostedFileWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[index]);
    }
}
```

in your unit test

```
var requestMock = new Mock<IRequestService>();
//you then setup the mock to return your fake data
//...
//and then inject it into your controller
var controller = new MyController(requestMock.Object);
//Act
response = controller.UploadFile();
```