# Unit Testing Asp.Net WebApi Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am trying to unit test an `ApiController` and set the current `HttpContext`, but every time I try and set the request information for the controller `HttpContext.Current` still seems to be null.

Here is the code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MakePayment()
{
     var config = new HttpConfiguration();
     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost/api/payment");
     var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
     var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "payment" } });

     var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
     var mockUserManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>(mockUserStore.Object);
     mockUserManager.Setup(x => x.GetUser(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new ApplicationUser());

     IPayPalService payPalService = new PayPalService(mockUserManager.Object);

     var paymentController = new PaymentController(payPalService);
     paymentController.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
     paymentController.Request = request;
     paymentController.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;

     Payment payment = paymentController.DepositMoney(50.00);

     Assert.AreEqual(payment.intent, "sale");
}
```

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can just use the `set` properties of `HttpContext` to set the Request. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20748142/346561) to a similar question is using a mocking framework to stub out the Request `get` instead.

Comment: Also, I am confused... is it the `HttpContext.Current` that is `null`? Or is it the `context.Request`?