# RhinoMocks AssertWasCalled throws Exception

Tags: c#-4.0, tdd, rhino-mocks-3.5

I am new to TDD and RhinoMocks.

I am trying to test AssertWasCalled but having problems.  The constructor to my test is as follows:

```
    public AccountControllerTests()
    {
        _webAuthenticator = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IWebAuthenticator>();
    }
```

And my test is like this:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AccountControllerCallsWebAuthenticator_CreateSignInTicketForGoodLoginCredentials()
    {
        const string username = "good-username";
        const string password = "good-password";

        var model = new LoginModel { Username = username, Password = password };

        _webAuthenticator.Stub(w => w.Authenticate(username, password)).Return(true);

        var mockHttpContextBase = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();

        var accountController = new AccountController(_webAuthenticator);

        accountController.Login(model);

        _webAuthenticator.AssertWasCalled(x => x.CreateSignInTicket(mockHttpContextBase, username));
    }
```

The error I get is:

Test method Paxium.Music.WebUI.Tests.Controllers.AccountControllerTests.AccountControllerCallsWebAuthenticator_CreateSignInTicketForGoodLoginCredentials threw exception: 
Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException: IWebAuthenticator.CreateSignInTicket(Castle.Proxies.HttpContextBaseProxy7f274f09b6124e6da32d96dc6d3fface, "good-username"); Expected #1, Actual #0.

I have now changed my code as below - Before and after code:

Before:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebAuthenticator _webAuthenticator;

    public AccountController(IWebAuthenticator webAuthenticator)
    {
        _webAuthenticator = webAuthenticator;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_webAuthenticator.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                _webAuthenticator.CreateSignInTicket(HttpContext, model.Username);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

After:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly IWebAuthenticator _webAuthenticator;
    private readonly HttpContextBase _contextBase;

    public AccountController()
    {

    }

    public AccountController(IWebAuthenticator webAuthenticator, HttpContextBase contextBase)
    {
        _webAuthenticator = webAuthenticator;
        _contextBase = contextBase;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_webAuthenticator.Authenticate(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                _webAuthenticator.CreateSignInTicket(_contextBase, model.Username);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

My tests now pass.  How I inject in the contextBase though when my controller is used for real??  I am using StructureMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you are receiving indicates that the Assert failed, i.e. the webAuthenticator object was **not** called with those specific arguments (hence expected #1, actual #0 exception message).

From the limited context you provide, I suspect that the **fake instance of the HttpContextBase (mockHttpContextBase) in your test is not the same object that's being passed to the webAuthenticator** from your production code.

There's two ways you can go about this: make the assert less strict or make sure the production code uses the fake http context object. If you don't care which instance of HttpContext gets passed to the webAuthenticator in this test, you can use argument matchers (Rhinomocks calls them [argument constraints](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+3.5.ashx#ArgumentConstraints)).
In your case, this would turn out something like this:

```
_webAuthenticator.AssertWasCalled(x => x.CreateSignInTicket(Arg<HttpContextBase>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Equal(username)));
```

Comment: I have changed my code to inject a context base but still a bit stuck - have added notes to my original question.  Hope this is the right way to do things?

Comment: Ok I realise injecting the HttpContextBase is wrong so I think I now understand about having a less strict Assertion.  I got he following to work:


`_webAuthenticator.AssertWasCalled(x => x.CreateSignInTicket(Arg<HttpContextBase>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Is.Anything));`

However the following says "Cannot access non static method 'Equals' in static context"


`_webAuthenticator.AssertWasCalled(x => x.CreateSignInTicket(Arg<HttpContextBase>.Is.Anything, Arg<string>.Equals(username)));`

Comment: My bad, the correct syntax is Arg<T>.Is.Equal(...) or the shortcut Arg<T>(...)

Comment: Note that it's still a perfectly valid choice to work with a fake HttpContext, although it looks a bit clunky for my tastes (for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747615/unit-test-asp-net-web-api-controller-with-fake-httpcontext) ). When I go this route, I prefer to provide a thin abstraction layer on top so I can cleanly test my logic in isolation without having to "set up the entire world" in my isolated unit tests. I put up a related example in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jovaneyck/8c81bf83e2e1dacd4548).

Comment: In your case the last approach might prove difficult since the Context is a property of the controller object itself. There are ways around this (using the subclass to test method for example), but this will only lead to more clunky code just to get it under test. The referenced stackoverflow answer or the less strict argument matchers might be the best ways to approach this problem.