# How to Test a C# WebApi post method that receive a FormData

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data

I have a controller with a post method:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {            
            System.Web.HttpFileCollection files = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
            var name = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("Name");
            var description = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("Description");
            HttpPostedFile theFile = null;
            if (files.Count > 0)
            {
                theFile = files[0];
            }
            var categoryPost = new CategoryPostDto()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = name,
                Description = description,
                Logo = theFile
            };
            //var categoryService = new CategoryServiceFake();
            try
            {
                //var newCategory = categoryService.AddCategory(name, description, files);
                var newCategory = categoryService.AddCategory(categoryPost);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, newCategory);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

On this controller I receive a formData from the front end, it works but i want to do the unitesting I tried to generate the context based on this post:

[Unitesting a post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747615/unit-test-asp-net-web-api-controller-with-fake-httpcontext)

I did this implementation on my unit test but it doesn't work:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            //arrange
            var formData = new NameValueCollection { { "Name", "Hotels" } };
            var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            request.SetupGet(r => r.Form).Returns(formData);
            var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            context.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);

            var myController = new CategoriesController();
            myController.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
            myController.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
            myController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(), myController);
            //act
            var response = myController.Post();

            CategoryPostDto categoryPostDto;
            Assert.IsTrue(response.TryGetContentValue<CategoryPostDto>(out categoryPostDto));
            Assert.AreEqual("Hotels", categoryPostDto.Name);            
        }
```

Comment: What does `It does not work` mean? you are going to have to be more specific if you want help from the community.

Comment: Just realized that the link referenced in your post is one I answered previously. The answer with the up votes is wrong and confuses MVC with Web API. If you review the answer I provided there you will see how to solve your problem. Basically you have tightly coupled your api controller to a static dependency which makes it difficult to test. HttpContext is also not available when unit testing as it is assigned by IIS which is not running when unit testing.

Comment: Hi NKosi, To be honest I didn't understand your answer could you explain more please???

Comment: Hi again @Nkosi, I implemented the answer of the other post but my controller doesn't have a constructor receiving requestMock.Object so I got a compilation error; also when you say "
//you then setup the mock to return you fake data" I got other errors, could you give some tips to solve this problem please...